# Как сверстать такой елемент?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Помогите, пожалуйста, сверстать такой элемент.
Там вместо белого фона будет картинка, ее должно быть видно в промежутке между красным и серым блоками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

вот так?

```css
.header {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #999;
    position: relative;
}

.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.icon:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    background-color: #ff0000;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="icon"><img src="https://c.wallhere.com/photos/9b/e1/1920x1080_px_lake_landscape_nature-1404461.jpg!s" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```